# Oracle / Netbeans Login Issue

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, toad, createuser

Oracle 11 XE / Netbeans 8.0.2 / Toad 12.7.1.11

Be forewarned: Noob on this stuff...

So I logged into Oracle via Toad as SYS and created a new user (Jason). Ended the connection, and connected under the new user. No sweat. Created a simple 2-column table and inserted 6 or 7 rows. Disconnected, reconnected (as Jason) and ensured my little table and data were still there. Great.

So I start a new project in Netbeans and try to connect to the db as Jason. JDBC won't connect, I get

```
"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:XE using OracleDriver (OR-28009: c
```

And that's all I have to go on. The error message is truncated (as above) by the New Connection Wizard's window.

Wierd -- It won't let my connect as SYS, either.

Wierder -- I CAN connect as SYSTEM. That account succeeds.

So I'm obviously missing something, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks that your project still using SYS connection...

when you connect as SYS user you need add as SYSDBA or SYSOPER option
the ORA-28009 error originally says

```
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER 
Cause: connect SYS/<password> is no longer a valid syntax
Action: Try connect SYS/<password> as SYSDBA or connect SYS/<password> as SYSOPER
```

rather than use SYS user and the options I'd recommend you create new user and grant him DBA role and then connect as this user:

```
connect sys/<password>@myserver as sysdba
create user mydba identified by mydbapassword;
grant dba to mydba;
connect mydba/mydbapasswor@myserver
...do what you need
```